# Mailchimp members activity

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've got some kind of script. Goal is:

- Get Mailchimp Lists
- For each list get members
- For each member get activity
- Store it

Does anyone know - if there any way to not use one API call for each member to get his activity?
I've got around 28 000 members.
28 000 API calls - seems as bad as it can be.

I've tried to get Lists Activity, but no way, it is always empty. So I really have to get exactly members activity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently attempting to do something very similar and there is a workaround, although I am not sure how feasible it is. Basically, you can do it through reports, email activity:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/

The challenge here will be that you will try to pull 28.000+ records at a time, therefore it will take a long time. From my brief calculations it can take up to 1 minute per 1000 records (you will need to loop through 1000 records at a time, otherwise it will most likely time out).

The larger problem is maintaining this 'database', if you have activity constantly happening (i.e. opens/clicks/bounces) then you will need to pull the whole campaign activity again and update wherever you store it. I've been trying to find a workaround with no success. You could use the 'since=2017-10-07T00:00:00+00:00' parameter, however it still returns a blank list when there is no activity unfortunately. If only 1000 members are actually active, it will return 27.000 rows of no activity. It would be great if there would be another parameter we could potentially apply to return only emails where there was an action.

Please let me know if you find a better solution.

P.S. - it might be worth reaching out to mailchimp support for this

Update - you can use the Mailchimp Export api: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-the-export-api/ and extract the email activity. I had huge issues unpacking it, please follow the links below: [Decode text response from API in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772489/decode-text-response-from-api-in-python-3-6)  and [Separate pd DataFrame Rows that are dictionaries into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792651/separate-pd-dataframe-rows-that-are-dictionaries-into-columns) . Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I've provided an update in my initial reply that should be the solution you need.