# Decode text response from API in Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to extract data from mailchimp export api, which returns responses based on the following specifications:

```
    Returns:
```

Parameter -     text

Description:
a plain text dump of JSON objects. The first row is a header row. Each additional row returned is an individual JSON object. Rows are delimited using a newline (\n) marker, so implementations can read in a single line at a time, handle it, and move on.

To get the data I am using:

```
response = requests.get(urldetails).text
```

If I use .json() it errors out with a JSON decode error. The output of the above is something along the lines of:

{data..}
{data...}

I am unsure whether each dict is on a separate row, however I am under the impression it's actually just one continuous string as many of my attempts to decode it ended up with an error 'str' object cannot be...etc. . I don't see the '\n' separators anywhere when I am using the .text method.

What's the best way of going about and make each dict a separate item in a list or a row in a dataframe (which I can unpack later).

Thanks

Comment: What is the endpoint you are querying? `https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/`?

Comment: Its the export API https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/campaignSubscriberActivity/ : https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-the-export-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the data from the `MailChimp export api` using a simple approach. Please note that I am using `f-strings`, only available in Python 3.6+.

```
import requests
import json


apikey = '<your-api-key>'
id = "<list-id>"

URL = f"https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/campaignSubscriberActivity/?apikey={apikey}&id={id}"

json_data = [json.loads(s) for s in requests.get(URL).text.strip().split("\n")]
print(json_data[0]['<some-subscriber-email>'][0]['action'])
```

Comment: Apparently splitlines() didn't work for him - why would stripping the string before splitting it make it function any different

Comment: Because the response has extra spaces that cause a `JSONDecodeError` if you do `json.loads` on a string with an extra space.

Comment: Ah right - I'm unable to test the api else I would've. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! - I tagged it as the correct answer, although I need to use a slightly different approach because I need everything in a neat dataframe (which looks like a challenge at the moment..). However, the '.text.strip().split("\n")' approach works!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the text response isn't insanely badly formed json, you can use the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). In particular, the loads() function.

```
import json
json_response = json.loads(response)
```

`loads()` loads JSON into a python dict from a string.

**EDIT:**
The Mailchimp API states that each JSON object is separated by a newline character. We can create a list of dicts with the following code:

```
# get response from GET request and load as a string
import json
json_resp = [json.loads(line) for line in response.split('\n')]
```

Comment: I had tried this, receiving the following error: 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response''. On the other hand if I use the .text version: json.loads(response.text), I get a different error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 113)

Comment: @DBa this is assuming the code on the question - `response = requests.get(urldetails).text` - has already been performed and therefore should already be a string if following the posted code.

Comment: Also, do you have a sample of what is returned? Or a URL I can test with?

Comment: Yes, sorry, realized afterwards, edited my answer to cover both with and without .text errors.

Comment: @DBa some sample of sorts would *really* help me help you

Comment: Unfortunately it's private information and I can't share, however here is a snip:  {"name@email.com":[{"action":"action","timestamp":"date","url":null}]}
{"name@email.com":[{"action":"action","timestamp":"date","url":null}]}

Comment: @DBa have you done print(response.text) to see if there are any newline characters or other discrepencies?

Comment: Yes, snip above is basically an edited copy-paste of print(requests.get(urldetails).text). It might be that the .text takes out any new line characters that the API provides

Comment: Also, after reading that are they not in a list? If it goes `{information} {information}` I wouldn't be surprised if it's erroring.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, they aren't in a list or anything.. that's why I mentioned the API details in my main post, maybe those would help make sense of the response.  I also believe there are no spaces  between {information} {information} , it's just one continuous string.

Comment: Thanks, however it doesn't do anything :( I am under the impression that .text takes away any new line characters. When I try it without .text I get the following error 'AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'splitlines' '

Comment: @DBa Can you tell me what print(response.encoding) says?

Comment: Without .text : 'UTF-8' , with .text : 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Comment: @DBa I doubt it will make a difference, but try new code on the edited answer. It is changed to `.split('\n')`. If that doesn't work, maybe `.split(u'\n')`?