# Separate pd DataFrame Rows that are dictionaries into columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am extracting some data from an API and having challenges transforming it into a proper dataframe.

The resulting DataFrame df is arranged as such:

```
Index      Column
0    {'email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}, {'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}
1    {'different-email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}
```

I am trying to split the emails into one column and the list into a separate column:

```
Index      Column1         Column2
0    email@email.com      [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}, {'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}
```

Ideally, each 'action'/'date' would have it's own separate row, however I believe I can do the further unpacking myself.

After looking around I tried/failed lots of solutions such as:

```
df.apply(pd.Series) # does nothing
pd.DataFrame(df['column'].values.tolist()) # makes each dictionary key as a separate colum 
where most of the rows are NaN except one which has the pair value
```

Edit:

As many of the questions asked the initial format of the data in the API, it's a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}, {'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]},{'different-email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}]
```

Thanks

Comment: while extracting the data you can directly use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that one - doesn't do anything either, tried with orient = 'index'   too which gives the following error. 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values''  I should mention that the initial data sits with each row as an item in a list.

Comment: can you post a sample of data in raw format rather than dataframe.

Comment: How did you make your DataFrame in that format? The problem is probably where you went from raw data to the DataFrame

Comment: Edited my initial question*

Comment: @DBa is something like: `pd.DataFrame({'email': k, **el} for dct in data for k, v in dct.items() for el in v)` what you're after?

Comment: Yes! thank you! if you make it an answer I can tag it as 'solved' the problem! great!

Comment: @JonClements Any Idea why the iteration drops (ignores) 'email' when the subsequent list is empty?

Comment: If you want that you can change `for el in v` to be `for el in v or [{}]` to ensure there's always one dictionary to unpack and hence get at least one row

Comment: thanks! - that did it, brilliant

Answer (score 1):

One naive way of doing this is as below:

```
inp = [{'email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}, {'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}
 , {'different-email@email.com': [{'action': 'data', 'date': 'date'}]}]
index = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
for each in inp: # iterate through the list of dicts
    for k, v in each.items(): #take each key value pairs
        for eachv in v: #the values being a list, iterate through each
            print (str(eachv))
            df.set_value(index,'Column1',k)
            df.set_value(index,'Column2',str(eachv))
            index += 1
```

I am sure there might be a better way of writing this. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! your solution also works, however someone posted a simpler version :) (would vote up but I don't have enough rep yet). However, as a note I get the following warning:   'FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead' which can be easily fixed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already read it as dataframe, you can use following -

```
import ast
df['Column'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
df['email'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: x.keys()[0])
df['value'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: x.values()[0])
```

Comment: Returns the following error on the first .apply 'ValueError: malformed node or string:'

Comment: That means all your strings are not of 'key : value' form